# Are Stack Exchange sites web apps?

Tags: discussion, scope, stackexchange

Are Stack Exchange sites web apps?

And if so, is it appropriate to ask questions on this site about how to use them?

Or do we make them go to the relevant meta site?

If we redirect them, why don't we just redirect all inquiries to somewhere else  (e.g. Facebook help)?

Answer (score 5):

If you have a general question about Stack Exchange *the engine*, in terms of its shared common behavior across multiple websites, it should be asked on http://meta.stackexchange.com .

If you have a question specific to *this website* , about *this specific topic* (that is, Web Apps), it should be asked here.

Comment: On Meta I assume?

Comment: Yes here is meta.webapps.stackexchange.com.

Comment: It's nice and convenient to say that, but doesn't that mean we should just redirect everyone to each web apps individual help site? (facebook.com/help etc) Why make a special case for Stack Exchange sites? Most people coming in via Google or whatever may not realise they're related and are just looking for somewhere to ask a question about a web app, which *could* include "How do I do $x on $stackexchangesite?".

Comment: The question should be asked in the most appropriate place.  All SE sites have meta, so questions about them should happen there.  It doesn't make sense to ask on the web apps SE site because they essentially already have their own SE site via meta.

Comment: Also, at somepoint a InsertPopularWebAppHere SE site might get created, at that point it would be valid to suggest any questions about PopularWebApp be asked on it's own SE site instead of the general WebApps one.

Comment: Sorry for the triple comment, but these are all separate thoughts.  For Jeff, Joel and Company, a different business model might be to offer meta SE sites to non SE sites.  I know this is similar to the old SE business model, but I thought I'd mention it.  meta.facebook.com, meta.google.com etc.  It would be a great web standard in my opinion, self documenting webapps anyone?