# Emphasizing that questions about Stack Exchange are off-topic here, even though logically they on-topic

Tags: discussion, scope, tag-wiki, stackexchange

The question [How to hide the welcome back message on Stack Exchange?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/117475/63572) was asked because I assumed **modifying** a website was perfectly suited Web Applications (Stack Exchange network is a subset of the internet). This assumption isn't explicitly explained in the [stack-exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stack-exchange) tag:

> Questions about Stack Exchange in general belong at Meta Stack Exchange. Questions about a specific Stack Exchange site belong on that site's Meta.

That understanding is further strengthened (though not explicitly confirmed) in [What topics can I ask about here?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic):

> Features of browsers which are directly related to the use of a web application (Greasemonkey scripts for a web application, etc.)

If anything, I suggest that we should emphasize this ban in the tag:

> This applies to any kind of question. We don't want to play logic game here.

What do you think?

---

The question is reasked [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/316361/260800). The comment section of the original question is below:

[image]

Comment: The linked question was deleted on July. Only you, diamond moderators and users with >10k rep could read it.

Answer (score 0):

## Short answer

I think that the [stack-exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stack-exchange) excerpt and wiki are fine.

## Extended answer

I think that it's a good idea to include on help/on-topic that questions about Stack Exchange should be made on Meta SE and about each site on the corresponding meta site because the tag "could" be lost (I think that the diamond moderators could prevent that), but I don't like the suggested phrase about the ban in the tag.

## Related

- [Are Stack Exchange sites web apps?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/67/88163)
- [Why in the world do we have [stack-exchange]?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3727/88163)

Comment: The suggested phrase is halfly pun, but I think the current excerpt is not clear enough. It should emphasize that even though logically the questions about the usage of Stack Exchange are on-topic here, practically they should be banned. That emphasis should go to the tag wiki because only then the question askers can be reminded right in their question

Comment: I have strengthened both the excerpt and wiki for [tag:stack-exchange]. Getting the help/on-topic page changed will require cooperation from a Moderator. I will try to restart the effort to burninate the tag.

Comment: @ale what I don't understand is that why you don't agree with the proposal to emphasize the fact that although logically questions about Stack Exchange on-topic here, they are still banned?